# Why arent Web API dlls distributed in the .NET Framework installer?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, gac

Web API as an example.

Since `System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll`, `System.Net.Http.Extensions.dll` etc are part of the .NET Framework why do we need to use Nuget to install them and also why are we now responsible for distributing them to our customers rather than just requiring customers to have the appropiate .NET Framework installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is part of the new, more modular approach that Microsoft takes on their framework.

It is much easier to have different versions of the dependencies running than the ones that the customer had installed. Also, this allows faster delivery of updates and changes than before (the entire framework had to be release for just one small change).

It also allows Microsoft to create a lightweight version of the framework and distribute that on different platforms, like Unix and mobile devices.

Comment: If nuget is an Open Source solution whos original goal was to allow distribution of packages for the open source community how can they pay for hosting Microsofts framework. Nuget have no revenue stream as far as i can see.

Comment: Who pays who? @Cat

Comment: Distributing all those files across the world isnt free bandwidth. Who is paying for the hosting and bandwidth?

Comment: that's fine for VS developers but what if this is needed on users machines to run your program